# border in nav-bar item when displaying current page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

This is the current nav-bar-item
[image: This is the current nav-bar-item]

This is the r.esult I want when clicking into the tab
[image: This is the result I want when clicking into the tab]

I am not sure whats the best approach to this.
I have tried by submitting a value to the navigate functions. and setting the global values in sharedService, and after, getting the values from sharedService to place with ngIf statement in html.

```
<div class="header-container">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light container">
                <a href='#' class="navbar-brand ">
                    <img src="../../assets/images/logo.png" width="100px" height="20" alt="" loading="lazy">

                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
                    <div class="navbar-toggler-icon"></div>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                            <a (click)="aboutShop()" class="nav-link">About SHOP</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                            <a (click)="workingWithUs()" class="nav-link">Work with Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                            <a (click)="pricing()" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a (click)="help()" class="nav-link">Help</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-block ml-4">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link"></a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a (click)="login()" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from '../sharedService';
import {Router} from '@angular/router'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  isHelp:false;
  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private sharedService: SharedService,
    ) {
     }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login(){
    this.router.navigate(['home/login']);
  }
  aboutShop(){
    this.router.navigate(['home/about-us']);
  }
  workingWithUs(){
    this.router.navigate(['home/working-with-us'])
  }
  pricing(){
    this.router.navigate(['home/pricing'])
  }
  help(){
  this.isHelp =true;
    this.router.navigate(['home/help'])
  }
}
```

```html
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
    private _help;

    set help(value){
        this._help = value
    }

    get help(){
        return this._help;
    }
}
```

I tried something like this

```
                            <li *ngIf="isHelp" class="nav-item" style="border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                            <a (click)="help()" class="nav-link">Help</a>
                        </li>
                        <li *ngIf="!isHelp" class="nav-item">
                            <a (click)="help()" class="nav-link">Help</a>
                        </li>
```

Comment: Is the navbar component common for all components or there is separate instance of navbar in each component?

Comment: the navbar component is common for all other components.
<app-header></app-header>   I place this in other components html

Comment: Okay then pass an input value to navbar component to identify which is the active one. Then use ngClass to toggle selected state.

Comment: Are there any examples available?

Comment: Can you create a stackblizt with what you have? Do one or two components with navbar. I'll update and give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add an Input to navbar component to indicate which component is currently active.

**navbar.component.ts :**

```
@Input() activeTab : string;
```

Then, in parent components give respective tags as input to navbar.

**component1.component.html :**

```
<app-navbar [activeTab]="'component1'"></app-navbar>
```

**component2.component.html :**

```
<app-navbar [activeTab]="'component2'"></app-navbar>
```

Toggle a class on each nav item based on the input tag.

**navbar.component.html :**

```
<li class="nav-item mr-3" [ngClass]="{'active' : activeTab=='component1'}">
    <a class="nav-link">Component1</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item mr-3" [ngClass]="{'active' : activeTab=='component2'}">
    <a class="nav-link">Component2</a>
</li>
```

**navbar.component.css :**

```
.nav-item.active {
    border-bottom : 2px solid grey;
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uyeb9r

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing in css `text_id:hover{border-bottom:1px solid black}` or the `<li>` of the text.

Ask me if you still have problems.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, but I dont mean on hover

Answer (score 0):

Try adding styles `border-bottom:1px solid grey` to a class and add the same to each `<li>` element and set a property to know which route is active.

Comment: Is the last snippet above similar?